# Calculate the percentage of a column

Tags: calculated-columns, tableau-desktop

I have loaded an Excel sheet into Tableau:

File_name, Category

A, CCCCC

A, CCCCC

B, CCCCC

C, EEEEE

D, EEEEE

E, WWWW

F, WWWW

I need to calculate: what percentage of Files are in Category CCCCC?

In this example, there are 6 distinct files (A, B, C, D, E, F). Two of them are in Category CCCCC (i.e. File A, B). Hence, the percentage of Files that are in Category CCCCC are: 2 out 6, i.e. 33%.

How do I calculate this percentage and display it on Tableau? Thank you!

Comment: How should the duplicate data rows be treated? (the first two rows are identical) or was that just a typo?

Comment: In your test data, each file is in exactly one category (only). Is that a rule you can rely upon? If so, the solution can be more efficient

Answer (score 0):

First drag category and then File Name to rows. Later right click on File name and choose measure (count distinct)-Step1 and change to discrete- Step 2. Now, again right click and choose Quick table calculation (Percentage of total) - Step3, then we can see the percentage across as below -

[image]